# SQL multiple select with group by problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a list of work orders with creation dates and completion dates.  I have found a GROUP BY statement on stack overflow but it doesn't seem to produce the results I expected.  My goal is to have the following

```
TERM  |  OPENED  |  CLOSED
----------------------------
01-15  |    432   |  243
02-15  |    543   |  859
03-15  |    102   |  437
04-15  |    153   |  342
...    |    ...   |  ...
01-16  |    175   |  256
02-16  |     55   |   30
```

This is the code I am using

```
select COUNT(wo) AS opened FROM wkaw 
WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01)
GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) + '-' + YEAR(org_date)

select COUNT(wo) AS closed FROM wkaw 
WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01) AND  cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + '-' + YEAR(cmpl_date)
```

I originally was using a CROSS JOIN to try to join the two statements together but it didn't produce expected results either.  My goal is that I want to eventually turn it into a VIEW, or Stored Procedure where it will select the results for the past year so that I can trend the data.

I'm not quite sure where to go from here.

UPDATED CODE BASED ON RESPONSE BELOW; it showed me how to fix my group by clause so I get the number of rows I expected now I just need to figure out how to use the join statement.

```
select MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date)*100) as dateinfo, COUNT(wo) AS opened FROM wkaw 
WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01)
GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) +  (YEAR(org_date)*100)
ORDER BY dateinfo

select MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date)*100) as dateinfo, COUNT(wo) AS closed FROM wkaw 
WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01) AND cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date)*100)
order by dateinfo
```

The order by isn't required was just using it to make it easier to read

Comment: Select MONTH("date") + '-' + YEAR("date") in the two queries, create an alias and inner join the 2 results on that alias. I assume you have an entry for each month - otherwise you can left outer join the two with a table that has all months inserted.

Comment: I think I realized where the error is, this code "MONTH(org_date) + '-' + YEAR(org_date)" produces a result where two of the selections or three of the selections would be the same; I think if I used multiply instead it would work better

Answer (score 1):

Use CTE for both queries, add the term column and make full join on it:

```
WITH
op(count,term) AS (
  SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(org_date) + '-' + YEAR(org_date) FROM ...
),
cl(count,term) AS (
    SELECT COUNT(*), MONTH(cmpl_date) + '-' + YEAR(cmpl_date) FROM ...
)
SELECT ISNULL(op.term,cl.term) AS term, ISNULL(op.count,0) AS opened, ISNULL(cl.count,0) AS closed
FROM op
FULL JOIN cl ON op.term=cl.term
```

Comment: Thanks!  I will have to learn more about CTE's and the WITH statement.  I tried using this but was not able to get it to work although it helped me come up with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
create table wkaw (wo int, org_date date, cmpl_date date);

insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-02-01', '2015-02-28');
insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-02-01', '2015-02-28');
insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-02-01', '2015-03-31');
insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-12-01', '2015-12-21');
insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-12-01', '2015-12-21');
insert into wkaw values (1, '2015-11-01', '2015-12-21');

select coalesce(x.mth, y.mth) period, coalesce(opened, 0) opened, coalesce(closed, 0) closed from (
 (
    select RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(org_date) AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(org_date) AS CHAR(4)) as mth, COUNT(wo) AS opened FROM wkaw 
    WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01)
    GROUP BY RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(org_date) AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(org_date) AS CHAR(4))
  ) x
  full outer join
  (
    select RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(cmpl_date) AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(cmpl_date) AS CHAR(4)) as mth, COUNT(wo) AS closed FROM wkaw 
    WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01)
    GROUP BY RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(cmpl_date) AS varchar(2)), 2) + '-' + CAST(YEAR(cmpl_date) AS CHAR(4))
   ) y
   on x.mth = y.mth
 )
order by 1
```

**Results**

```
period  opened closed
02-2015  3      2
03-2015  0      1
11-2015  1      0
12-2015  2      3
```

NOTE: I haven't given any consideration to performance here.

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped me think of a good way to do what I needed to do.  I really appreciated the help

Answer (score 0):

In the end using both Shire's reply and Pavel's response I was able to come up with the following SQL code to produce the results I was looking for.  I am not sure how this affects performance but it seems to work well.

```
select o.dateinfo, opened, closed FROM (
select MONTH(org_date) + (YEAR(org_date)*100) as dateinfo, COUNT(wo) AS opened FROM wkaw 
WHERE org_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01)
GROUP BY MONTH(org_date) +  (YEAR(org_date)*100)) o
INNER JOIN (
select MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date)*100) as dateinfo, COUNT(wo) AS closed FROM wkaw 
WHERE cmpl_date >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1,MONTH(GETDATE()),01) AND cmpl_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY MONTH(cmpl_date) + (YEAR(cmpl_date)*100)) c
ON o.dateinfo = c.dateinfo
ORDER BY o.dateinfo
```

Thanks for the help gentleman!

Cheers,
Johnathan

Comment: But inner join does not return months, where were either any opened and no closed or no opened and any closed....

Comment: That comment makes sense; it produces the results I expect but that is because we never have a month with no closed or no open work orders; but it definitely is possible so I should consider that.  Thanks Pavel!

Answer (score 0):

There is another possibility using sql analytic functions:

```
WITH c(oterm,cterm) AS
(SELECT MONTH(org_date) + '-' + YEAR(org_date),MONTH(cmpl_date) + '-' + YEAR(cmpl_date) FROM wkaw),
a(term,cterm,opened,closed) AS
(SELECT DISTINCT oterm, cterm, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY oterm), COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY cterm) FROM c)
SELECT term, opened, closed
FROM a
WHERE term = cterm
```